# swig js filter "last"

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, swig

source json:

```
{

"rss": {
    "$": {
        "version": "2.0",
        "xmlns:metadata": "http://rss.rbc.ru/metadata",
        "xmlns:rbc_news": "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/",
        "xmlns:wfw": "http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    },
    "channel": {
        "item": [
            {...},
            {...},
            {...},
            {...},
            {...}
        ]
    }
}

}
```

Swig js template, that handles source json:

```
{%set root = rss.channel %}

{
"items":[
    {% for item in root.item %}
        {
            "category":"{{item['metadata:category']}}",
            "title":"{{ item.title }}"
        }{% if item|last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
]
}
```

I can't figure out how to select last item. In the output it seems that every item is the last item and the first item in the context of rss.channel.item. So the output is:

```
 { "items":[ 
            { 
              "category":"autonews", 
              "title":"sometitle1" 
            }, 
            { 
              "category":"sport", 
              "title":"sometitle2" 
            }, 
            { 
              "category":"realty", 
              "title":"sometitle3" 
            },...
```

It's required, that comma would appear only after the last item. I can't solve the problem in this expression:

```
{% if item|last %},{% endif %}
```

Swig's documentation says:

```
// my_arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
{{ my_arr|last }}
// => c
```

So I wonder what's the mistake?

Comment: if it's like jinja or twig , the loop should have a $last variable or something like that,look it up

Comment: I've skimmed documentation, and it makes sense that last filter do the job http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/filters/#last .But it does not.

Answer (score 0):

The "|last" is a filter, which make you easier to handle the return value.
If you're trying to do something when the last item comes in, you should use 
"{% if loop.last %}things to do{% endif %}"

see http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/tags/#for